# Passing HTMLPage as a return value of WCF REST Service

Tags: wcf, html

I want to pass HTMLPage as a return value of my WCF REST Service to my HTML5 application (client).
Is there a way to do this? Or any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way: return a `Stream` from the operation you want to return the HTML page from, and set the outgoing content type to "text/html". You can find more information about it at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx.

If you don't want to create the HTML page yourself, and instead want something which can convert some object into the page, you'll need to dig deep into the innards of WCF, and use something like a message formatter to do the conversion for you. That's really a lot more work, so I'd strongly recommend the simple way, unless you already have some sort of mapping between objects and its representation.